# how to declare template of template class

Tags: c++, templates

How can declare template of a template class?? see below code:

```
File: A.h
class A
{
    ...
    ...
};

File: B.h
template <typename U>
class B
{
    ...
    ...
};

File C.h
template <class T>
class C
{
    ...
    ...
};

File C.cpp
//In this file I am able to write template declaration for class A(non-template class)
#include "A.h"
template C<A>; //this works fine. 

How can I write the same for class B(which is a template class.)
#include "B.h"
template C<What should I write here for class B?>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, B is also a template, so something like `C<B<A>>` would work.

Note that some compilers see `>>` as a shift operator, and requires `C<B<A> >`.

Comment: Note that C++03 compilers are *required* to see `>>` as shift operator, while C++0x (probably going to be C++11) compilers are/will be required not to need the space here.

Comment: @Christopher - The compilers I have used are not that strict, and seems to sort out the difference from context.

Comment: Most compilers do not really follow any standard by default, and very few do so even with their “strict” flags. Still, this is a very well-known deficiency of the C++03 standard, so I sure hope your compilers at least clearly spell out in their documentation that they violate the spec in this regard. (Not that I have a big problem with that in this particular case.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `B` as *type* argument to `C` class template, then you can write this:

```
template class C<B<int> >; //i.e provide the some type B template class
       //^^^^ this is needed for explicit instantiation!

C<B<A> >  variable;
C<B<short> >  *pointer = new C<B<short> >();
```

Comment: I don't think it parses in *any* C++ version. An explicit instantiation requires to write `class` before the class name, I think. Also, what purpose do you want to achieve??

Answer (score 2):

The `C` template expects a non-template type so that it can generate a class. That's why `C<A>` works: `A` is not a template. However, `C<B>` doesn't work, since `B` is only a *template* for a type itself. You need to have some type to instantiate the `B` template.

For instance, this could work:

```
C<B<A> > x;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just write it like this:

```
C< B< A > > c;
```

If you find that confusing then you can use a typedef:

```
typedef B<A> MyB;
C<MyB> c;
```